# How can I get a relation by the endpoints using the "Fetch entity by property" action in rules?

Tags: rules, entities

**Short version**: I want to fetch a relation by the endpoints.  The relation already exists in the database.  How can I use the *Fetch entity by property* action to return the relation?

**Long version**:

I'm using the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) modules on Drupal 7.  I have a relation type that is created between two users (the endpoints are user entities).  The relations I am trying to fetch have already been created.

When one user sends a message to another with the [Private Message](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module, I want to fetch the relation between the sender and the recipient.

Here is the rule:

Event: *A message is sent* (from Privatemsg module)

Action: *Add a variable* (List of any entity items, `endpoint_list`)

Action: *Add an item to a list* (Add `privatemsg-message:author` to `endpoint_list`)

Action: *Add an item to a list* (Add `recipient` to `endpoint_list`)

Action: *Fetch entity by property* (Entity type: Relation, Property: Endpoints, Value: `endpoint_list`, Limit results: 10, provides `fetched_relation`)

However, when I try to perform another action (loop, data comparison, data set, etc.) on `fetched_relation`, I get the following error in the rules debug log:

> 4.468 ms Unable to get the data value for the variable or parameter value. Error: Missing data values.

It appears that the relation is not fetched.  However,

1. I am sure the relation exists in the database with the correct endpoints (the relation appears in the UI correctly and I even checked the MYSQL table).
2. When I add an action *Print message* and print `privatemsg-message:author:name` and `recipient:name`, it shows me the names of the correct users, so those variables appear to be correct.
3. I have looked at the documentation for [fetching relations with rules](https://drupal.org/node/1276398) but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just a humble thought - a shot in the dark really. In some cases, in order to work with a particular field (e.g. a noderef attached to an article) we have to tell Rules that this field exists (adding a condition: entity has field...|| node is of type article). I'm just wandering then if the errors perhaps stem from a missing object? Got this idea while watching this screencast http://nodeone.se/sv/node/754

Comment: @Bisonbleu Thanks for the idea, but in this case, I am setting the type of all variables upon declaration and fetching entities by property, so as I understand it Rules must know what types are being used.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fetch relation by endpoint with the help of @marcusx and the patch of @MahmoudMostafa (drupal user names). You can find all in the issue [Fetch Relation by Endpoints in rules](https://drupal.org/node/1302788).

I had also linked your issue to that one.

Resuming the steps here, you need to:

- apply the [patch](https://drupal.org/files/relation-query_endpoints-1302788-16.patch)

> 1. Create a list of any entiy
> 2. Put your endpoints in the list
> 3. Use the endpoint list to fetch the relation
>
> cited from marcusx comment

(I see you already know this).

Bear in mind that

> "fetch relation by endpoints" action in rules, [...] fetches all the relations for the endpoints in the chosen list, even if the list contains only one endpoint.
> In this (sub)case, the action fetches all relations pointing to the selected endpoint, whatever the other endpoint.
>
> cited from my comment

And that the resulting fetched_relation is a list (I see you already know this as well).

I believe you only need to apply the patch, which you didn't mention in your question. Is it true?